# Gridview edit not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have the following gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdAll" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false"
        Width="40%" GridLines="None" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2">
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltColor22" />
        <RowStyle CssClass="AltColor21" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table width="100%" class="TableBorder">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" />
                                <hr />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="left" class="TableBorder">
                                <asp:GridView ID="GrdContent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                    Width="100%" GridLines="None" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" 
                                    OnRowDataBound="GrdContent_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GrdContent_RowEditing"><%----%>
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kiosk ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblKiosID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                              <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtKiosk" runat="server" Text ='<%#Eval("HBEmailID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>

                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text ='<%#Eval("HBEmailID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>

                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  CommandName="Edit"
                                                    Text="Edit" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server"  CommandName="Update"
                                                    Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"  CommandName="Cancel"
                                                    Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

In this, edit functionality is not working.

In clicking of edit button, it shows me nothing. (It should show me textbox to edit)

Following is code:

```
Protected Sub GrdContent_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs)

    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(TryCast(sender, Control).Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
    Dim index As Integer = row.RowIndex

    CType(row.FindControl("GrdContent"), GridView).EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    DBName = CType(row.FindControl("lblName"), Label).Text
    bindContentGrid(CType(row.FindControl("GrdContent"), GridView), DBName)
End Sub
```

Please help me, it does not gives me error, but it also not showing me textbox to edit.

Comment: `c#` tag deleted which is irrelevant..

Comment: nope, relevent answer in c# can also help me, i have mentioned it at two places.

Comment: Try setting a break point on the row editing event and use try catch to find what error or values your are getting when edit is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be on the following code

```
bindContentGrid(CType(row.FindControl("GrdContent"), GridView), DBName)
```

If that code does not return any records, then nothing will be displayed. Make sure it is returning some rows.